# Live edit, live reload with Chrome Workspaces, grunt and Less

Tags: less, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, livereload

I have setup a project with Bootstrap's less files and gruntjs in order to be able to have live edit in the Chrome Workspaces.

Hereunder is my Gruntfile.js. It auto-compiles less files into the desired style.css and creates a source map file when I save my changes. I'm also able to edit and save less files from Chrome Workspaces after adding the project directory to the Workspaces.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-!(cli)').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        less: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    sourceMapFilename: 'public/css/style.map',
                    sourceMapBasepath: 'public/css'
                },
                files: {
                    'public/css/style.css': 'less/style.less'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            all: {
                files: ['less/**/*.less'],
                tasks: ['less'],
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);
};
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to see the live reload of my modifications on the less files via Sublime Text 2 or Chrome Workspaces directly in the browser without refreshing the page.

**What am I missing?** I have to map files? What file to what file exactly? Will I need to map multiple the same way or only one file.

I've also added an image where you can see the files tree.

[image: project files tree]

FYI, also please note that the style.less imports the bootstrap less files and my custom less files.

```
// Core variables and mixins

@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "showtime/lib";
@import "showtime/intro";
@import "showtime/nav";
@import "showtime/portfolio";
@import "showtime/contact";
@import "showtime/footer";
@import "showtime/album";
```

**Update** **If edit from the Elements tab, my style.less file gets overwritten with the content that is also in style.css and then it works. What am I doing wrong ?**

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the only I was able to make everything work is by putting the less files in my css folder.